# How to make a port open?

Tags: linux, iptables, nmap, port

When I ping, there is reply.

```
$ ping 10.26.14.16
64 bytes from 10.26.140.160: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.525 ms
```

When I ping with port, there is no reply.

```
$ nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.16
5016/tcp closed unknown
```

Question: How to make port 5016 open?

Comment: You make a Port "open" by having a service listening on it. You might need to also adjust firewall rules so you can reach the service.

Answer (score 2):

As said @ucarus in this [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652997/how-to-make-a-port-open#comment1227146_652997):

> You make a Port "open" by having a service listening on it.

E,g: Use `nc` to start the port listener as 5016 on the `10.26.14.16` machine:

```
nc -l 5016 &
```

Then:

```
nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.16
```

Comment: @rinto Do not close the terminal after executing `nc` command.

Comment: When I use "nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.16", it says Host is up. But PORT  STATE=closed. SERVICE=unknown.

Comment: I have A & B linux machines . A can reach 10.26.14.16:5016. I want B  to forward packets to A  to reach 10.26.14.16:5016.   I use "iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.26.14.16  -p tcp --dport 5016 -j DNAT --to-destination <linux B IP ADDRESS>" in B linux.

Comment: Still I can ping 10.26.14.16 from B.  When I execute "nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.50", it says Host Up.  Port=516/Tcp State=Unknown. Service=Unknown,

Comment: @rinto - please update the original question with your observations / questions.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, netcat is not the right tool to hold a port open. The reason being that netcat listener is a raw socket tool and expects further commands from you. For example, you held TCP 5016 open on server side. You then ran nmap scan against the server. During the scan, the client sent TCP SYN packets. The server did not know how to respond because you did not tell it how to respond. In other words, you are supposed to program it how to respond (just like in a TCP protocol). As a result the server sent RST to the client in response to SYN and the connection died. When this happens when no service is running on the port, and the port will appear to be closed from a client perspective.

To easily accomplish your needs, I suggest you use python because it is pre-installed in most Unix-like OS. You can use the HTTP module (no extra installation will be required). In this case when nmap scan is executed on client side, the server (which is now acting a simple HTTP server) will know how to respond to TCP SYN packets. To get started, depending on Python v2 or v3:

Python 2 (server side):

```
$ python -V
$ cd /tmp
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5016
```

Python 3 (server side):

```
$ python -V
$ cd /tmp
$ python3 -m http.server 5016
```

Nmap (client side):

```
$ nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.16
```

The command `$ cd /tmp` was not necessary but a caution since the web server will index your current directory. However `/tmp` is a safe place to run your tests.

Comment: It is a security risk to run a script that exposes the current directory from `/tmp`: it may contain things like credentials readable by the current user (eg. for an X session), among other things. It would be much better to use an emphemeral directory, ie. `cd "$(mktemp -d)"`.